# Is there a standard for generating system public keys?

Tags: runtime, public, key

I have noticed the entropy for system public key generation is prefixed with patterns like `modlpy/proxy____`.

1. Is there a documented standard for the length or format of these prefixes?
2. What is the purpose of the trailing underscores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in the line you are referring to gets hashed:

```
let entropy = (b"modlpy/proxy____", who, height, ext_index, proxy_type, index)
    .using_encoded(blake2_256);
```

So there is no difference here what prefix is used. Just something unique enough that it is unlikely to be duplicated somewhere else by accident.

For other instances of `struct PalletId`, this is specifically defined as:

```
/// A pallet identifier. These are per pallet and should be stored in a registry somewhere.
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Eq, PartialEq, Encode, Decode, TypeInfo)]
pub struct PalletId(pub [u8; 8]);
```

So you will find in another places, this is specifically truncated or extended to 8 characters.

I have no context as to why this struct and pattern was not used here.